# Not able to access google sheets in R studio (Rmarkdown file)

Tags: google-sheets, error-handling, google-sheets-api

[Till today this program was running very smoothly but, when I try to access the google sheet after the authentication still showing the err in R (Error in functionalist[k] : Not Found (HTTP 404).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgVJ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

the tool might use the older version sheets api which is shut down
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api

they need to use the latest sheets v4 api